# cannot find esp8266 via boardmanager

Tags: arduino-ide

i'm using arduino ide 1.8.12 opened preferences window and did enter

http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json, https://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json

(all comma separated) into the Additional Board Manager URLs field. then i opened the boardmanager (Strg+Shift+I) and enter 'esp' in the search field. BUT I CAN'T FIND "esp8266 by ESP8266 Community". it's not listed. WHAT CAN I DO NOW ?

additive : is there a way to include a locally available json file in the arduino as a library? 
the file 
    package_esp8266com_index.json 
is in the directory 
    C: \ Users \ [user] \ AppData \ Local \ Arduino15

thanks in advance

Comment: did you restart the IDE?